# Python Xpath get the value only from root element

Tags: python, xpath, web-scraping

i'm using XPath to scrap one web page, but i'm with trouble with one part of the code:

```
<div class="description">
   here's the page description
   <span> some other text</span>
   <span> another tag </span>
</div>
```

i'm using this code to get the value from element:

```
description = tree.xpath('//div[@class="description"]/text()')
```

i can find the correct div i'm looking for, but i only want to get the text "here's the page description" not the content from inner span tags

anyone know how can i get only the text in the root node but not the content from child nodes?

Comment: that xpath expression shouldn't contain the spans' contents, only the content of the text nodes which are direct children of the div: `["\n   here's the page description\n   ", '\n   ', '\n']`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The expression you are currently using would actually match the top-level text child nodes only. You can just wrap it into [`normalize-space()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/XPath/Functions/normalize-space) to clean up the text from extra newlines and spaces:

```
>>> from lxml.html import fromstring
>>> data = """
... <div class="description">
...    here's the page description
...    <span> some other text</span>
...    <span> another tag </span>
... </div>
... """
>>> root = fromstring(data)
>>> root.xpath('normalize-space(//div[@class="description"]/text())')
"here's the page description"
```

To get the complete text of a node including the child nodes, use the [`.text_content()`](http://lxml.de/lxmlhtml.html#html-element-methods) method:

```
node = tree.xpath('//div[@class="description"]')[0]
print(node.text_content())
```

Comment: Thanks, but i think my question isn't clear enought, i don't want to get the content from child nodes, only from root node

Comment: @Dennis my bad, but u should be good to go with the expression u currently have - it would match the top level text nodes only..